# Header(Location url) not passing parameters

Tags: php, http, web

I have a form in the file `index.php` that sends its post log-in parameters to the script `login.php`.

If the password is wrong I call the following function

```
header("Location: absPath/index.php?error=1")
```

from the `login.php` file. Although the functions sends me to the right page, the parameter is not sent. If i do a `var_dump($_GET)`, it will print an empty array.

Any ideas?

Comment: First of for login details use form method POST and you can retrieve posted form values using echo '<pre>'; print_r($_POST); die;

Comment: Immediatey after the `header` you should have an `exit` (die) statement.

Comment: @Martin, yeah i have the exit after each header call.

Comment: make sure you don't have an additional redirect (e.g. from a .htaccess file) that drops the parameter

Comment: Code? Might have to do something with your htacces. This shall work as-is.